# Como puedo poner dos tipos de NS en la misma clase - Xcode Swift OSX

Tags: xcode, macos

¿Como podría poner NSTexField, NSViewController juntas en la misma clase de cocoa?

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation


class Licencia: NSTextField , NSViewController {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift y Objective-C son herencia única, no puedes tener más de una superclase para una clase.